# Удалить элемент списка двухмерного списка, не меняя его структуры

Tags: python, list

Как удалить второй элемент двухмерного списка, не меняя структуру списка

`[[0,1],[1,9]]` --------> `[[0,],[1,]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например:

```py
print([[x[0]] for x in lst]) 
# [[0], [1]]
```

Но запятых не будет. "Висящие запятые" были бы если бы это были кортежи, а не списки.

Ну или если там больше элементов внутри, то можно удалять первый элемент "по месту", а не делать новый список:

```py
for x in lst:
    del x[1]
print(lst)
```